# WP/PHP getting API data and using hook

Tags: php, api, wordpress

Below are the two things I'm trying to solve, logically. This is just a proof of concept; and I'm not implementing this on real data nor via full plugin at this time. Just looking at logic and syntax solutions.

**Below are the (2) requirements.**

**1.)** Given an API route for retrieving a specific record, do the following:

- Get the id param
- Return a 404 if the record isn't found
- Return a response with the record if it is found

Route format:

```
/publishers/(?P<id>\d+)

/publishers/397
```

**2.)** Add a WordPress hook to determine the value of the visible property on some item. Then use that hook elsewhere to change the value to false;

Below is what I have so far. Which appears correct; but just would like to see if there is a more optimal way, and/or this is still best approach. Just some feedback on my code solution; via the above two points.

**My Code solutions:**

---

```
<?php
function get_publisher( \WP_REST_Request $request ) {   
    $request = json_decode( $request );
    $publisher_id = $request[ 'ID' ];
    if ( empty( $publisher ) ) {

        $response = [
            'status'    => 404,
            'data'      => [
                'errors' => [
                        'general' => 'Sorry, no record was found.'
                ],
            ],
        ];
        return json_encode( $response );
    }
    $response = [
        'status'    => 200,
        'data'      => [
            'publisher' => $publisher,
        ]
    ];
    return json_encode( $response );
}
function modify_item( $item ) {
    $item->visible = apply_filters( 'item_visibility', true ); 

    return $item;
}
function hide_item() {
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'item_visibility', 'hide_item' );
```

Answer (score 1):

- You will need to settle on the variable name containing `$request[ 'ID' ];`. At the moment, you are using `$publisher_id` and `$publisher` ...which of course is a script fouling typo. I'd probably avoid declaring the variable, because I don't find a declarative coding style to be very beneficial in this case.
- You could use a different syntax to declare your array to be less verbose. For example:

  ```
   $response['status'] = 404;
   $response['data']['errors']['general'] = 'Sorry, no record was found.';
  ```
- By writing an `if-else`, you can avoid rewriting `json_encode()`.

..I don't WP so I cannot say if there any native techniques to leverage.

The first function could look like this:

```
function get_publisher(\WP_REST_Request $request) {   
    $request = json_decode($request);
    if (empty($request['ID'])) {
        $response['status'] = 404;
        $response['data']['errors']['general'] = 'Sorry, no record was found.';
    } else {
        $response['status'] = 200;
        $response['data']['publisher'] = $request['ID'];
    }
    return json_encode($response);
}
```